# Aggregation failed using $in in MongoDB conditional aggregation query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to use $in in MongoDB query similar to this one

This query works for me and uses **{ $gte: [ "$likes_count", 1000 ] }**

```
    db.Tweets.aggregate(
       [
          {
             $project:
               {
                 _id: 0,
                tweet: 1,
                 convert:
                   {
                     $cond: { if: 

{ $gte: [ "$likes_count", 1000 ] }

, then: "1000 likes or more", else: "less than 1000 likes" }
                   }
               }
          }
       ]
    )
```

However when I use **{tweet:{$in:[/tesla/i,/rocket/,"coffee"]}}** in almost the same query I get aggregation failed error

```
db.Tweets.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project:
           {
             _id: 0,
            tweet: 1,
             convert:
               {
                 $cond: { if: 

{tweet:{$in:[/tesla/i,/rocket/,"coffee"]}}

, then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }
               }
           }
      }
   ]
)
```

I know that in a simpler query the $in works

db.Tweets.find({tweet:{$in:[/tesla/i,/rocket/,"coffee"]}} , {likes_count:1, tweet:1, _id:0})

However I am not understanding the correct way to format $in aggregation method
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/

I have tried swapping with **{ $in: [ "tesla", "$tweet" ] }** but this still creates aggregation failed error

```
db.Tweets.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project:
           {
             _id: 0,
            tweet: 1,
             convert:
               {
                 $cond: { if: 

{
        $in: [ "tesla", "$tweet" ]
      }

, then: "contains words", else: "does not contain words" }
               }
           }
      }
   ]
)
```

Please help. I am still new to MongoDB and curly braces, the queries look almost the same to me apart from using $in and the $gte.

Comment: Please provide sample input documents - and of course the error your get. "I get aggregation failed error"  is not really helpful.

Comment: `/tesla/i,/rocket/` are regular expressions. You need plain strings

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in the documentation you provided here:
[$in agg docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/)

"
Unlike the $in query operator, the aggregation $in operator does not support matching by regular expressions.
"